# collapse this panel by default

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

Need this panel to collapse by default, it currently is open when the page is loaded. I've tried googling things and nothing seems to be working.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-title">

               Subcontractors
            <ul class="panel-tools">
                <li><a class="icon minimise-tool no-print"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body table-responsive" class="panel-collapse collapse">

            <table id="subcontractor_table" class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name</td>
                        <td>Last Name</td>
                        <td width="200px">Hours Quoted</td>
                        <td width="200px">Rate</td>
                        <td width="200px">Amount Quoted</td>
                        <td width="100px">Actions</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="subcontractor_table_body"></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I meant Bootstrap 3

Comment: Could I interest you in reading a bit about [ask] and [mcve]? Also, here is your solution: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `data-toggle="collapse"` and `data-target="#[YOURDIV]"` to your link, so it knows what to collapse.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-title">
            Subcontractors
            <ul class="panel-tools">
                <li><a class="icon minimise-tool no-print" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsible"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="collapsible" class="panel-body table-responsive panel-collapse collapse">

            <table id="subcontractor_table" class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name</td>
                        <td>Last Name</td>
                        <td width="200px">Hours Quoted</td>
                        <td width="200px">Rate</td>
                        <td width="200px">Amount Quoted</td>
                        <td width="100px">Actions</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody id="subcontractor_table_body"></tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Subcontractors Panel -->
```

Here, I added `id="collapsible"` to the div and referenced it in `data-target="#collapsible"`

Edit: since you're using a link, you could also set the `href` of the link to `#collapsible` and ommit the `data-target`:

```
<a class="icon minimise-tool no-print" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapsible"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine on my side. Have you set up bootstrap correctly?

Comment: Yeah should be, I'm at work lol. Thanks so much for your help anyways though!

Comment: If you say so ;) Glad it works (might want to accept the answer)